# on change event not firing on localhost but works fine on server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, apache

I have centos serevr with apache, where the on chnage event on  is fired as expected but for some reason when it's not working on localhost.

I have checked browser console and got rid of all the warnings and errors except for google oAuth **uncaught exception( this is the only error on browser console on localhost which is not there on server)**.
Tried putting the code block in another script tags with jquery  document ready wrapper but no luck.

its simple code

```
$('#div').on('change','.class_name_of_selectElement',function(){
   alert('check');
 });
```

is it possible for the event not being fired because of that one uncaught exception or something else is going on here?
to be honest the code is mess with multiple js libraries. not sure what is causing the issue. please help

Comment: That error will most likely be the cause of the problem. You need to debug and fix it

Comment: browser console errors will generally prevent the rest of your JavaScript code from executing

Comment: when you say `on localhost which is not there on server` you mean you're opening the page directly in your browser, like`file:///<path-to-file>`?

Comment: @GrafiCode no, it's on Apache as well.

Comment: nevertheless you will likely need to resolve this error (or comment out the offending code temporarily) in order to test that the rest is working

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan & @ADyson even I thought so. But I tried on a different page  to manually throw an exception using the JS `throw`  and have a `on change` event after that, its working fine.

Comment: We can't really help you debug the problem without knowing what code that causes it.

Comment: @Pandurang there are certain scenarios where it will cause a full crash, and sometimes you can get away with it. I can't say I can define for you right now exactly what those scenarios are, but I have noticed it occasionally. Depends on the exact circumstances. Whilst we do not have enough of your code to verify anything, I would suspect that the scenario you created for your test was different in some important aspect from the real code.

Comment: @ADyson resolving this error is slightly difficult as it has to do with google OAuth. google doesn't allow me to put localhost as valid domain. will have to do with commenting it  I guess. Thanks.

Comment: which OAuth flow are you using, exactly? https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow and https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer for instance actually gives an example of using localhost as a valid JavaScript origin.

Comment: @ADyson thanks for your help. will try again with OAuth settings.

Comment: @ADyson thanks for the link. I added localhost in OAuth and got rid of that uncaught exception. but it didn't solve my problem. after digging for a while found out that everything was breaking after this line in view `$query = @unserialize(file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/php/' . $ip));`  and it was not generating any warnings because of the `@` sign. anyway fixed it now. Thanks again.